C# build problems with multiple submodules
I want to setup the following C# project structure with the project ProjA, ProjB and ProjC which include each other as git submodules like:
ProjA
-ProjB
--ProjC
-ProjC
So ProjA and ProjB include ProjC.
When I want to build the solution of ProjA I get the following error:
CS0006  Metadata file '\ProjA\ProjB\ProjC\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\ProjC.dll' could not be found ProjB.
I assume that ProjB is refering to "its" ProjC and not the ProjC which is part of the solution of ProjA.
How can I fix this? ProjA and ProjB should be buildable.
Thank you for your help!
Edit: those are the csproj files:
ProjA:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ProjB\ProjB.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ProjC\ProjC.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Proj B:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ProjC\ProjC.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


I don't quite understand this project struture, can you add .csproj files? And furthermore, the error is clear enough: the dll file could not be found. How does this file come about?

Thank you for your answer! I added a part of the csproj files

This doesn't make sense, the path referenced in your project files (..\ProjB\, ..\ProjC\) doesn't match the path in the error (\ProjA\ProjB\ProjC\).

C# projects generally should not be nested inside subdirectories like this because of how, by default, (since 2016) all .cs files are recursively included in all subdirectories - so ProjA will end-up including all of ProjBs source files. I recommend you redesign your project's filesystem arrangement so projects are all at the same filesystem depth.

Also,do you have a good reason for choosing to use git submodules for your dependencie here instead of using a NuGet <PackageReference />?
